# How to write array elements to a rangelist using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this rangelist as the destination and a row of values that should be written to the destination.
I was thinking of iterating through the row of data and also through th rangelist and set value along the way, but I can't find a way to iterate through the elements in the row of data.
Here's the piece of code I'm working on:

```
function moveItem() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A6:D9").getValues();
  let data = [];
  const ref = sheet.getRange('A13').getValue();
  const variation = sheet.getRange('C13').getValue();

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == ref && values[i][4] == variation) {
      data.push(values[i])
    }
  }

  const destRng = [
    "B17", "B18", "D17", "D18"
  ]

  const rngList = sheet.getRangeList(destRng).getRanges();
  for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    rngList[n].setValue(data[n])
  }
}
```

Here's a view of the flow:
[image]

Here's a practical example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKr-faDQOk7VBpiTVnxUEMllXbe0ON9-gKwfJii3G0U/edit?usp=sharing

`getValues()` gets 01 row of data. Each column of this row should go into the destRng as we loop through these columns and through the destination ranges.

Now, this is getting the first element of data and writing it to all destination cells. How can I go through these data elements?

Thank you!

Comment: can you add better code, meaning to include "values" and "sheetCadProd.getRangeList" and also the expected result ?

Comment: Hi, @JafarJabr! Just added the begging of the code to it and bit more on the situation VS expectation. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the sample input sheets of "sheetCadProd" and "sheetBDCadProd" and the sample output situation of "sheetCadProd" you expect as the images? And can I ask you about the detail of `Now, this is getting the first element of data and writing it to all destination cells. How can I go through these data elements?`?

Comment: A [mcve] doesn't require so many `destRng` values, by the other hand the sample input data and the expect results are missing.  I suggest you to, 1. minimize the code in the question, 2. add some sample input data and the corresponding expected result 3. Show what you tried to debug your code (you could add some console.log / use the debugger to see if the variables are getting the expected values, among other things).

Comment: Sorry, @Rubén. Usually, after so much intake/learning, I desperately resort to Starckoverflow and forget to ellaborate on the problem. Just added some more info to the question. Thanks of keeping the quality of this community which helps me so much.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, Thanks for looking at this one. I've added a practical example above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additianl information, I cannot understand the logic when "A13" and "C13" are "Text1" and "Text1C", "B17:B18" and "D17:D18" are `Text1, Text1B` and `Text1C, Text1D`, respectively. Isn't "Variation" of "C12" the column "B"? Can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving your goal?

Comment: Is the value on C13 (`Text1C`) correct? The heading is Variation but `Text1C` isn't on the Variation column (`B6:B8`)

Comment: Just corrected it, @Rubén! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your additional information, I cannot understand the logic when "A13" and "C13" are "Text1" and "Text1C", "B17:B18" and "D17:D18" are `Text1, Text1B` and `Text1C, Text1D`, respectively. I thought that in your sample Spreadsheet, "Variation" of "C12" might be from the column "B". When my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][0] == ref && values[i][4] == variation) {
    data.push(values[i])
  }
}
```

##### To:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (values[i][0] == ref && values[i][1] == variation) { // Modified
    data.push(values[i])
  }
}
if (data.length == 0) return;  // Added
data = data[0]; // Added
```

- In this modification, when the cells "A13" and "C13" are "Text1" and "Text1B", respectively, "B17:B18" and "D17:D18" become `Text1, Text1B` and `Text1C, Text1D`, respectively.

#### Note:

- In this modification, I used your showing sample Spreadsheet and your script. When your actual situation is different from your showing sample Spreadsheet, this modification might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- When `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. If you want to reduce the process cost in your situation, you can do this using Sheets API as follows. In this case, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

  - From

    ```
      const rngList = sheet.getRangeList(destRng).getRanges();
      for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
        rngList[n].setValue(data[n])
      }
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
      const reqs = destRng.map((e, i) => ({ range: `'${sheetName}'!${e}`, values: [[data[i]]] }));
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data: reqs, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ss.getId());
    ```

Answer (score 1):

The values and the destination range should have the same number of elements, assuming that this is true, there is no need to have nested for loops, a single for loop is enough.

In other words, insted of

```
for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < rngList.length; i++) {
      let dado = data[n] 
      rngList[i].setValue(dado)//It sets the first value throughout the rngList
    }
  }
```

use

```
for (let n = 0; n < data.length; n++) {
  rngList[n].setValue(data[n])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rúben! However, when I run it, it doesn't write anything. I've tried replacing ```data.length``` for ```rngList.length``` and it overwrote some of the fields. ```data``` does contain the row of data, though. Would you have any idea on why? Thank you!

Comment: not sure which to choose as the answer, though, as they complete each other. Gracias!